# compute sum of the components of the solution to a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A x = b$, where $A\in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible. Let $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_n)^T$. How to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ without solving the equation? For a given $C\in \mathbb R$, how to check if $x_1+\cdots +x_n = C$ is consistent with $Ax=b$ without solving the equation?

Comment: I guess you are not allowed to compute the inverse of $A$?

Comment: No. Don't want to compute the inverse of $A$.